# When should desktop app save to database using UoW?

Tags: database, domain-driven-design, desktop-application

So one thing I didn't really think about when designing this personal finance application was WHEN (not HOW) to persist the data.  I'm using DDD, a 4-tier architecture, and EF.

It struck me when I added a new Transaction, Account, etc. that it's immediately saved to the DB.  However, this is not how most desktop applications work.  Even TurboTax creates a file that it wants you to save with Ctrl+S.

So my question is, with DB persistence, does it only make sense for me to call `uow.SaveChanges()` in response to a user's save command (via Ctrl + S)?  Or should I do it with every addition/deletion/etc.?

Now that I think about it, I think GnuCash just uses a file to save all the data (which seems odd to me).

Comment: TurboTax is fundamentally a document-based program like Excel, not a business-domain record and transaction-based system like the one you're building.  Document-based programs lend themselves to document-style saving; business-domain applications do not, and require a more robust and feature-rich persistence mechanism.  You've provided a very compelling example of why there's no one right way to build a software system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, with DB persistence, does it only make sense for me to call uow.SaveChanges() in response to a user's save command (via Ctrl + S)? Or should I do it with every addition/deletion/etc.?

It depends.

Treating each user action as a command to be evaluated and stored in the domain model is one reasonable choice.  Each command is represented by a message passed from your application component to your domain model component.  I imagine the seam I would need if I were using the application as an interface to a web api -- each command would be a POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE that the server would handle.

Another might be to separate the concepts of "draft" and "publish" in your domain model.  Each editing session gets its own draft (with its own life cycle and cleanup rules), and the Save button triggers a command that publishes the current draft.

You could treat the drafts as something that belongs to a transient, in memory model, and the published reports as living in the database -- there's no rule that says all of your aggregates need to be part of the same data store (although there are complexities when you try to coordinate changes among separated stores).

Another interesting possibility is to consider the edits as being made in an [occasionally connected client](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/1980-cqrs-not-just-for-server-systems), with the save button acting as a "synchronize the in-memory edits with the remote store" action.